# Not able to create Firestore Database in Firebase as non-owner account

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collaborator account in firebase and the owner has assigned me the permissions for **Firebase Admin**. When I try to create Firestore Database and navigate to screen it shows

> To manage Cloud Firestore, ask a project owner for the necessary
> permissions site.

What can I do or ask the owner, to get this issue fixed and be able to create Firestore DB in Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase pages on permissions delegates the [Firestore permissions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions#firestore) to the [Cloud Datastore permissions](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/access/iam#permissions) documentation, which has these relevant snippets:

> `datastore.locations.get` Get details about a database location. Required to create a new database.
>
> `datastore.locations.list`    List available database locations. Required to create a new database.

and

> **Required roles to create a Datastore mode database instance**
>
> To create a new Datastore mode database instance, you require either the **Owner** role or the **Datastore Owner** role.
>
> Datastore mode databases requires an active App Engine application. If the project doesn't have an application, Firestore in Datastore mode creates one for you. In that case, you require the `appengine.applications.create` permission from the **Owner** role or from an IAM custom role containing the permission.

From that it sounds like asking them to grant you the [**Datastore Owner** role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#datastore-roles) is the easiest and most likely to work.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Only thing I am still confused is, where I/Owner can see the screen to change the permissions for this. In Firebase Settings -> Users & permissions, Owner can only see option to assign me Owner/Editor/Viewer and some pre-defined firebase roles. Can you please guide on that as well. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is indeed only possibly in the Google Cloud console, not in the Firebase console. The Firebase console provides a link in the relevant access popups, but you can also start at: console.cloud.google.com and find your Firebase project there. Keep in mind: in the backend Firebase projects are just Cloud projects with some extra flags  on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. I was finally able to get access to create and manage firestore DB.